# targets the type which is not an '@Entity' type

Tags: java, hibernate

Quiero hacer un programa que teniendo dos tablas llamadas cliente y ejercicio, con su respectivo `idCliente` e `idEjercicio` (foreingKey), se junten estas foreingKey en una tabla llamada `cliente_ejercicio` y añadirle dos atributos nuevos.

### Esta es mi base de datos:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `gym` ; USE `gym` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gym`.`cliente` (   `idCliente` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `nombreCliente` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE 'utf8mb3_bin' NOT NULL,   `apellidos` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE 'utf8mb3_bin' NOT NULL,   `edad` INT NOT NULL,   `altura` DOUBLE NOT NULL,   `peso` DOUBLE NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`idCliente`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gym`.`ejercicio` (   `idEjercicio` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   `nombreEjercicio` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE 'utf8mb3_bin' NOT NULL,   `numeroSeries` INT NOT NULL,   `numeroRepeticiones` INT NOT NULL,   `cargaKg` INT NULL DEFAULT 0 NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`idEjercicio`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gym`.`cliente_ejercicio` (   `idCliente` INT NOT NULL,   `idEjercicio` INT NOT NULL,   `repeticionesReales` INT NULL DEFAULT 0 NULL,   `diaSemana` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT ' ' NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`idCliente`, `idEjercicio`),   INDEX `fk_cliente_has_ejercicio_ejercicio1_idx` (`idEjercicio` ASC) VISIBLE, INDEX `fk_cliente_has_ejercicio_cliente_idx` (`idCliente` ASC) VISIBLE,   CONSTRAINT `fk_cliente_has_ejercicio_cliente`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idCliente`)
    REFERENCES `gym`.`cliente` (`idCliente`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,   CONSTRAINT `fk_cliente_has_ejercicio_ejercicio1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idEjercicio`)
    REFERENCES `gym`.`ejercicio` (`idEjercicio`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Al ejecutar me salta esta excepción:

Tengo problemas al utilizar una relación ManyToMany en Java (Eclipse)

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Association 'com.hibernate.model.Cliente.clienteEjercicio' targets the type 'com.hibernate.model.ClienteEjercicio' which is not an '@Entity' type**

Por lo que yo entiendo la expeción me dice que no tengo declarado @Entity en la clase ClienteEjercicio, pero si la tengo declarada. Añado el código que tengo realizado:

### Clase ClienteEjercicio

```
package com.hibernate.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import jakarta.persistence.AssociationOverride;
import jakarta.persistence.AssociationOverrides;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.MapsId;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cliente_ejercicio")
@AssociationOverrides({ @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.cliente", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idCliente")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.ejercicio", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idEjercicio")) })
public class ClienteEjercicio implements Serializable {

    private ClienteEjercicioKey pk = new ClienteEjercicioKey();
    int repeticionesReales;
    String diaSemana;

    public ClienteEjercicio() {
        super();
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    public ClienteEjercicioKey getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(ClienteEjercicioKey pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @Transient
    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return getPk().getCliente();
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        getPk().setCliente(cliente);
    }

    @Transient
    public Ejercicio getEjercicio() {
        return getPk().getEjercicio();
    }

    public void setEjercicio(Ejercicio ejercicio) {
        getPk().setEjercicio(ejercicio);
    }

    @Column(name = "repeticionesReales")
    public int getRepeticionesReales() {
        return this.repeticionesReales;
    }

    public void setRepeticionesReales(int repeticionesReales) {
        this.repeticionesReales = repeticionesReales;
    }

    @Column(name = "diaSemana")
    public String getDiaSemana() {
        return this.diaSemana;
    }

    public void setDiaSemana(String diaSemana) {
        this.diaSemana = diaSemana;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        ClienteEjercicio that = (ClienteEjercicio) o;

        if (getPk() != null ? !getPk().equals(that.getPk()) : that.getPk() != null)
            return false;

        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (getPk() != null ? getPk().hashCode() : 0);
    }

}
```

### Clase ClienteEjercicioKey:

```
package com.hibernate.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Embeddable;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
@Embeddable
public class ClienteEjercicioKey implements Serializable {

    private Cliente cliente;
    private Ejercicio ejercicio;

    @ManyToOne
    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public Ejercicio getEjercicio() {
        return ejercicio;
    }

    public void setEjercicio(Ejercicio ejercicio) {
        this.ejercicio = ejercicio;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;

        ClienteEjercicioKey that = (ClienteEjercicioKey) o;

        if (cliente != null ? !cliente.equals(that.cliente) : that.cliente != null)
            return false;
        if (ejercicio != null ? !ejercicio.equals(that.ejercicio) : that.ejercicio != null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result;
        result = (cliente != null ? cliente.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (ejercicio != null ? ejercicio.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

}
```

### Clase Cliente:

```
package com.hibernate.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinTable;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cliente", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "idCliente") })
public class Cliente implements Serializable {

    private int idCliente;
    private String nombreCliente;
    private String apellidos;
    private int edad;
    private double altura;
    private double peso;
    
    private Set<ClienteEjercicio> clienteEjercicio = new HashSet<ClienteEjercicio>(0);
    
    /**
     * Constructor.
     */

    public Cliente() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * 
     * @param nombreCliente
     * @param apellidos
     * @param edad
     * @param altura
     * @param peso
     */

    public Cliente(String nombreCliente, String apellidos, int edad, double altura, double peso) {
        super();
        this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.altura = altura;
        this.peso = peso;
    }
    
    public Cliente(String nombreCliente, String apellidos, int edad, double altura, double peso, Set<ClienteEjercicio> clienteEjercicio) {
        super();
        this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.altura = altura;
        this.peso = peso;
        this.clienteEjercicio = clienteEjercicio;
    }

    /**
     * Getter.
     * 
     * @return idCliente: Devuelve el ID del cliente.
     */

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "idCliente", unique= true)
    public int getIdCliente() {
        return this.idCliente;
    }

    /**
     * Setter.
     * 
     * @param idCliente: Establece el valor de ID del cliente.
     */

    public void setIdCliente(int idCliente) {
        this.idCliente = idCliente;
    }

    /**
     * Getter.
     * 
     * @return nombreCliente: Devuelve el Nombre del cliente.
     */

    @Column(name = "nombreCliente")
    public String getNombreCliente() {
        return this.nombreCliente;
    }

    /**
     * Setter.
     * 
     * @param nombreCliente: Establece el valor del Nombre del cliente.
     */

    public void setNombreCliente(String nombreCliente) {
        this.nombreCliente = nombreCliente;
    }

    /**
     * Getter.
     * 
     * @return apellidos: Devuelve los Apellidos del cliente.
     */


    @Column(name = "apellidos")
    public String getApellidos() {
        return this.apellidos;
    }

    /**
     * Setter.
     * 
     * @param apellidos: Establece el valor de los Apellidos del cliente.
     */

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    /**
     * Getter.
     * 
     * @return edad: Devuelve la edad del cliente.
     */

    @Column(name = "edad")
    public int getEdad() {
        return this.edad;
    }

    /**
     * Setter.
     * 
     * @param edad: Establece el valor de la edad del cliente.
     */

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    /**
     * Getter.
     * 
     * @return altura: Devuelve la altura del cliente.
     */

    @Column(name = "altura")
    public double getAltura() {
        return this.altura;
    }

    /**
     * Setter.
     * 
     * @param altura: Establece el valor de la altura del cliente.
     */

    public void setAltura(double altura) {
        this.altura = altura;
    }

    /**
     * Getter.
     * 
     * @return peso: Devuelve el peso del cliente.
     */

    @Column(name = "peso")
    public double getPeso() {
        return this.peso;
    }

    /**
     * Setter.
     * 
     * @param peso: Establece el valor del peso del cliente.
     */

    public void setPeso(double peso) {
        this.peso = peso;
    }
    
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.idCliente", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<ClienteEjercicio> getClienteEjercicio() {
        return this.clienteEjercicio;
    }
    
    public void setClienteEjercicio(Set<ClienteEjercicio> clienteEjercicio) {
        this.clienteEjercicio = clienteEjercicio;
    }

}
```

### Clase Ejercicio:

```
package com.hibernate.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinTable;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToOne;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ejercicio", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "idEjercicio") })
public class Ejercicio implements Serializable  {
    
    private int idEjercicio;
    private String nombreEjercicio;
    private int numeroSeries;
    private int numeroRepeticiones;
    private double cargaKg;
    
    private Set<ClienteEjercicio> clienteEjercicio = new HashSet<ClienteEjercicio>(0);

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */

    public Ejercicio() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * 
     * @param nombreEjercicio
     * @param numeroSeries
     * @param numeroRepeticiones
     * @param cargaKg
     */

    public Ejercicio(String nombreEjercicio, int numeroSeries, int numeroRepeticiones, double cargaKg) {
        super();
        this.nombreEjercicio = nombreEjercicio;
        this.numeroSeries = numeroSeries;
        this.numeroRepeticiones = numeroRepeticiones;
        this.cargaKg = cargaKg;
    }
    
    public Ejercicio(String nombreEjercicio, int numeroSeries, int numeroRepeticiones, double cargaKg, Set<ClienteEjercicio> clienteEjercicio) {
        super();
        this.nombreEjercicio = nombreEjercicio;
        this.numeroSeries = numeroSeries;
        this.numeroRepeticiones = numeroRepeticiones;
        this.cargaKg = cargaKg;
        this.clienteEjercicio = clienteEjercicio;
    }

    /**
     * Getter.
     * 
     * @return idEjercicio: Devuelve el ID del ejercicio.
     */

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "idEjercicio", unique= true)
    public int getIdEjercicio() {
        return this.idEjercicio;
    }
    
    /**
     * Setter.
     * 
     * @param idEjercicio: Establece el valor de ID del ejercicio.
     */

    public void setIdEjercicio(int idEjercicio) {
        this.idEjercicio = idEjercicio;
    }

    /**
     * Getter.
     * 
     * @return nombreEjercicio: Devuelve el Nombre del ejercicio.
     */

    @Column(name = "nombreEjercicio")
    public String getNombreEjercicio() {
        return this.nombreEjercicio;
    }

    /**
     * Setter.
     * 
     * @param nombreEjercicio: Establece el Nombre del ejercicio.
     */

    public void setNombreEjercicio(String nombreEjercicio) {
        this.nombreEjercicio = nombreEjercicio;
    }

    /**
     * Getter.
     * 
     * @return numeroSeries: Devuelve el Numero de series del ejercicio.
     */

    @Column(name = "numeroSeries")
    public int getNumeroSeries() {
        return this.numeroSeries;
    }

    /**
     * Setter.
     * 
     * @param numeroSeries: Establece el Numero de series del ejercicio.
     */

    public void setNumeroSeries(int numeroSeries) {
        this.numeroSeries = numeroSeries;
    }

    /**
     * Getter.
     * 
     * @return numeroRepeticiones: Devuelve el valor del Numero de repeticiones del
     *         ejercicio.
     */

    @Column(name = "numeroRepeticiones")
    public int getNumeroRepeticiones() {
        return this.numeroRepeticiones;
    }

    /**
     * Setter.
     * 
     * @param numeroRepeticiones: Establece el valor del Numero de repeticiones del
     *                            ejercicio.
     */

    public void setNumeroRepeticiones(int numeroRepeticiones) {
        this.numeroRepeticiones = numeroRepeticiones;
    }

    /**
     * Getter.
     * 
     * @return cargaKg: Devuelve el valor de la Carga en Kg del ejercicio.
     */

    @Column(name = "cargaKg")
    public double getCargaKg() {
        return this.cargaKg;
    }

    /**
     * Setter.
     * 
     * @param cargaKg: Establece el valor de la Carga en Kg del ejercicio.
     */

    public void setCargaKg(double cargaKg) {
        this.cargaKg = cargaKg;
    }
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.ejercicio")
    public Set<ClienteEjercicio> getClienteEjercicio() {
        return this.clienteEjercicio;
    }

    public void setClienteEjercicio(Set<ClienteEjercicio> clienteEjercicio) {
        this.clienteEjercicio = clienteEjercicio;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de hibernate tienes? A falta de otras librerías como spring lo más probable es que necesites actualizar tu versión de hibernate